# How i can receive data from Html FORM to my Email?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

i want to receive data that submitted from Html FORM to my company email or any email and show to the user the thank you page.

```
<form  method="post" action="">
    <div class="form-wrap">
        <label class="form-label" for="contact-name">Name</label>
        <input class="form-input" id="contact-name" type="text" name="entry.1430967391" data-constraints="@Required">
    </div>
    <div class="form-wrap">
        <label class="form-label" for="contact-phone">Phone</label>
        <input class="form-input" id="contact-phone" type="text" name="entry.465166061" data-constraints="@Required @PhoneNumber">
    </div>
    <div class="form-wrap">
        <label class="form-label" for="contact-email">E-Mail</label>
        <input class="form-input" id="contact-email" type="email" name="entry.1309662733" data-constraints="@Required @Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-wrap">
        <label class="form-label" for="contact-message">Message</label>
        <textarea class="form-input" id="contact-message" name="entry.329807308" data-constraints="@Required"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-button">
        <button id ="myBButton"class="button button-primary-gradient btn-sm" type="submit" onclick="pr11"><span>Send</span></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Give us more details, Is that plain php project or you use some framework? Have you tried process the form in php already? If so, is there any library you researched to send the email?

Comment: As @Beniamin is implying, the way you retrieve the data from the HTTP/HTML POST depends on the language or framework you are using.  You tagged PHP, so you should read about accessing the contents of the $_REQUEST or $_POST arrays on the receiving page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php.

Comment: You can use `action="mailto:xyz@abc.com"` to send a form to xyz@abc.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a serverside language and you selected PHP as a tag to your question so I will recommend that.

Here is a link that will help you understand and implement what you need. Ask questions if you have any. Glad to help!

https://html.form.guide/email-form/php-form-to-email.html

Comment: can i have your Skype please. because you help me a lot and i want you to help me for more small details .

Comment: and what about if i want to add phone field to my form? , i need just to duplicate the name line in the PHP code and replace the name whit phone and it will work fine ?

Comment: pretty much it yes. in your HTML, whatever name you have as your name eg: `<input type="text" name="phone" />` in your php code, this will be read as `$_POST['phone']` or `$_GET['phone']` depending on whether your form `method` is GET or POST. for most forms, post is a better way to handle submissions.

Comment: what about if i want to resend a welcome email to the user that he entered his email on the FORM ?

Comment: I mean to make the sending action as an automated action ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to send the user an email after he has filled the form? If that is what you mean, in the link I sent you, there is an option to do that, you will just have to send 2 seperate emails using the mailer function

Comment: i am little newbie on PHP coding and i will glad if you help me .this my skype: live:sighowyou20

Answer (score 0):

have you used PHPMailer?
go through https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.